# Count articles in category

Tags: joomla

I would like to display article count in a single category.

```
$categoryName = "CategoryName";
$n = count($this->category->$categoryName);
echo "This category has ".$n." articles in it!";
```

This is not working (example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a parameter allowing you to do this already. Assign a *Category List* or *Category Blog* Menu item and then choose under the *Category Options* parameters tab. Change **No Articles Message** to show.

The reason that your code isn't working - is because a single category is just represented by `$this->category`.

However for either Category Blog or Category List layouts you can simply use:

```
$categoryName = "CategoryName";
if($this->category->title==$categoryName) {
    count($this->category->getNumItems(true))
}
```

http://docs.joomla.org/Help25:Menus_Menu_Item_Article_Category_Blog#Category_Options

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The default category layout contain the count of the articles in it.

take a look at this `components\com_content\views\categories\tmpl`

Also you can found the count `count($item->getChildren())`

Hope this may you..